# Custom command for '\begin{environment}...\end{environment}'

Tags: latex

To enter a bit of dialogue using the `screenplay` package, I have to use

```
\begin{dialogue}{Johnny} Some dialogue. \end{dialogue}
\begin{dialogue}{Jane} I see. \end{dialogue}
```

It gets a bit tedious after a while. Is it possible to specify a custom command so that I can use something like

```
\dialogue{Johnny} Some dialogue.
\dialogue{Jane} I see.
```

instead?

Comment: depending on what editor you use, you might want to look into a snippets package as well.

Comment: +1 This is a really interesting question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
\newcommand{\dialogueline}[2]{\begin{dialogue}{#1} #2 \end{dialogue}}

% Usage example:
\dialogueline{Johnny}{Some dialogue.}  
\dialogueline{Jane}{I see.}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but if anybody knows how to replicate the exact format requested by the original poster, it would be nice to see.

Comment: I think that's about as close as you can get to what the poster wants. There has to be braces around the text so LaTeX knows where to put `\begin{dialogue}` and `\end{dialogue}` properly. Also, I used `\dialogueline` in case there's already another command named `\dialogue`, but if that's not the case, then the poster can replace `\dialogueline` with `\dialogue` instead if it causes no errors.

Answer (score 11):

You can in fact get exactly what you want:

```
\newcommand{\dialogueline}{\begingroup\catcode`\^^M=12 \dialogueline@EOL}
{\catcode`\^^M=12\gdef\dialogueline@EOL#1#2^^M{\begin{dialogue}{#1}#2\end{dialogue}\endgroup}}
```

This code needs to be [`\makeatletter`-protected](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=atsigns)—either surrounded by `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` (*edit*: this means that you put `\makeatletter` before the definition, and `\makeatother` after it), or in a `.sty` file.  Note that an environment named `dialogue` defines a command named `\dialogue`, so you need a different name.  Do not change the formatting!

The way it works is that `\dialogueline` is a command which takes no arguments, but instead expands to multiple sequences.  First, a group-opening token, to put whatever follows in its own scope.  Second, the `` \catcode`^^M=12 `` sequence.  LaTeX assigns each letter a [*catcode*](http://www-sop.inria.fr/miaou/tralics/doc-symbols.html): a number which says what type it is.  For instance, the backslash is catcode 0, the command-name constructor; letters are catcode 11; and non-letter printing characters, such as the at sign, are catcode 12.  This sequence makes `^^M`, the newline character, have catcode 12, so we can interact with it.  Finally, we write out the command `\dialogueline@EOL`, which does the heavy lifting.

Next, we define `\dialogueline@EOL`.  We do so within a group where the newline character is catcode 12, just as it will be where `\dialogueline` is expanded.  Note that this is why you cannot break the second line with a newline—it would be interpreted as text.  Next, we define `\dialogueline@EOL` to take two arguments, ending with a newline; it expands by taking the first argument (which you pass in braces) and passing it as an argument to the `dialogue` environment, and passing the second argument (everything after the first and before the end of line) as the body of the environment.  Finally, `\dialogueline@EOL` ends the group opened in `\dialogueline`, so that the change to the catcode of `^^M` is not visible anywhere else.  Given this, you can write

```
\dialogueline{Johnny} Some dialogue.
\dialogueline{Jane}   I see.
```

and everything should work.

Comment: That's rather clever. I didn't know about `\catcode` up until now. While my solution will work for anything put inside the braces, yours will work for one-liners and is closer to the asker's requested syntax.

Comment: The trick is actually less about catcodes and more about pattern-matching in `\def`: you could also do something like `\gdef\dialogueline@EOL#1:#2^^M` to be able to write `\dialogueline Johnny: Some dialogue.`.  The catcode switch is so that the end of a line isn't just treated as a space character and ignored, but is instead treated as a matchable character.  You're right that this may outlaw some valid strings (though some of these can be permitted by hiding the matched string in curly braces, e.g. `\dialogueline {Alexander: the Great}: Die!`), but it's nice for shortcuts and embedded DSLs.

Comment: Real nice. Works just as you say. Thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: Well, actually I got a "use of \dialogueline doesn't match its definition" error when I used \makeatother, but it works just fine with \makeatletter.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that---the definition has to come *after* `\makeatletter` and *before* `\makeatother`.  (The former changes the catcode of `@` to that of a letter, so it can be part of control sequence names; the latter changes it back.)

Comment: Got it. It worked just fine sandwiched between two \makeatletter commands, but I guess that's not really the correct syntax. Thanks again.

Comment: This is way too technical compared to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you assume that each dialog occupies one paragraph (usually, it starts and ends with a double-line paragraph break), then there is another way to have  `\dialogue`  take just one argument:

```
\newif\indialog \indialogfalse
\def\dialogue#1{\ifindialog \end{dialogue}#1\begin{dialog}\else 
                \everypar={\end{dialogue}\indialogfalse \everypar={}}#1\indialogtrue\begin{dialogue} 
                \fi}
```

That code is kind of dirty and un-Latexy —it sets `\everypar` without caring about its existing content— and Latex has cleaner abstractions for doing it, which I have forgotten, but the principle should be clear.

Comment: That's clever, I hadn't seen this technique before.